# Containerization of a vue.js app with nginx runs into redirect loop

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js

I am building a vue.js app which I want to serve using nginx. However, it fails with the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

In the beginning nginx tried to redirect to port 80 when the external port was 8000. That's why I added the line `absolute_redirect off;` to the config. However, this only caused a redirect loop:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
172.17.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2019:15:24:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
```

Here's the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        off;
    keepalive_timeout  60;
#    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And here is the website config:

```
server {
  absolute_redirect off;
  port_in_redirect off;
  location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      try_files  / /index.html;
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655869/how-to-use-vue-js-with-nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try_files  / /index.html;
```

This loops back to your location `/`, change it to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` should solve your problem